# C# WPF non-mvvm page converter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm code some app with different pages in one window. First of all i use MVVM pattern, but later i understand what using this pattern for so small application is not necessary.

But im MVVM version i use page converter for xaml binding. 
Let me show what i mean:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Frame
    Name="MainFrame"
    Content="{Binding ApplicationViewModel.CurrentPage, Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.Instance}, Converter={conv:ApplicationPageValueConverter}}"
    NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```

In ValueConverter i use switch with enum parameter, and return new Page(),
like:

```
case ApplicationPage.HelloPage:
                    return new HelloPage();
```

So i regreet MVVM pattern.

But now then i use this container, it doesnt work at all. 
I use backend file for pages and window. In window backend file i use property with OnPropertyChanged. But when page changes, converter dont work.

Comment: IMO there is no application "to small" for MVVM. Sure, the benefits aren't realized as much but getting good practice is always good.

Comment: Apart from that, I don't see enough here to definitively say what your issue is, you may need to show the VM at least. For what its worth, that's a pretty weird way to get to your VM. Also check your output window for binding errors

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: As others mentioned, more info is needed. But if I would have to guess: make sure that the object you are sending for conversion has the type you are expecting (or testing against).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, i dont use VM at all. Just backend file of window and pages like hellopage.xaml.cs. Ok, how can i check output window for binding errors?

Comment: @Marty, i use breakpoint at switch statement in valueconverter, but he doesnt stop. But then i use viewmodel that method works. How can i debug converter? What he recieve and when he convert value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found answer.

I forgot specify DataContext of backend file.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");

    DataContext = this;
}
```

So, that's it! =)

Comment: Just to be clear, the view as the VM is *terrible* practice as far as MVVM goes.